# How to guaranteed write into file in multithreading with exceptions?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, streamwriter

This is a simplified example

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(() => Method1()).Start();
            new Thread(() => Method2()).Start();
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void Method1()
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"h:\data.txt"))
            {
                int i = 100000000;
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    sw.WriteLine(i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Method2()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(6000);
            throw null;
        }
    }
}
```

StreamWriter doesn't write the data into file if exception occurs too early and in another thread. File data.txt is empty at the time when exception occurs.

I played with this situation a little and found a bunch of workarounds:

1. If I increase the sleep interval for the exception's thread (and decrease interval between writings into file) the file will be filled with data. It is not a choice because I don't know when an exception occurs.
2. As a consequence of previous workaround I can decrease the buffer size of the stream writer. But it seems not working if I set it too small - for example, this code

   FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"h:\data.txt", FileMode.Create);

   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Default, 10))

doesn't work because the first writing operation occurs only when about 385 integers are waiting in the buffer to be written into file.

3. File will be filled if I close the writer before exception occurs. But that is not a good choice - I have to write into file from 1 to 10 times per second. It is not a good idea to open and close the writer so frequently, is it?
4. I can catch the exception like this

   private static void Method2()
   {

   ```
   try
   {
       Thread.Sleep(6000);
       throw null;
   }
   catch
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Exception!");
   }
   ```

   }

and all will be OK - no application termination and file will be filled pack by pack. But that is not the case also - I can't control when and where exceptions occur. I try to use try-catch everywhere but I can miss something.

So the situation is: StreamWriter's buffer is not full, exception occured in another thread and is not catched, so the application will be terminated. How not to lose this data and to write it into file?

Comment: Did you try to `Flush` the stream instead of closing it. That should take care of saving the data into the file while letting the stream open and accepting further data

Comment: That said, I would recommand you to check about the [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) keyword and the [`Mutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) object which exists to solve these concurrency problems

Comment: You can catch any exception in program if you simply wrap Main method in `try { } catch { } finally {}` block and in `finally` block wait for working Thread to finish executing

Comment: Also Google "Critical Section".

Comment: @Sidewinder94 Flush() and AutoFlush is a solution. I tried it and it works. Thank you! If you make your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: For others - I don't think the lock is a choice. These two threads are nearly independent. The multithreading is here only to show that one part of an application can ruin another by just uncaught exception.

Comment: @Alex34758 Yeah, I've read the example a little too fast ^^'

Comment: @Kevin How to use your approach in WPF app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flushing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) the stream will ensure that all of it's content is pushed into it's underlying file.

That will take care of ensring all of the data is saved after you completed an operation and that a following exception will not make your application loose data.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your situation you are assuming that there is a bug somewhere and the process might be terminated at any time. You want to save as much data as possible.

You should be able to call `Flush` on the `StreamWriter`. This will push the data to the OS. If your process terminates the data will eventually be written by the OS.

In case you cannot convince `StreamWriter` to actually flush for some reason you can use a `FileStream` and write to that (pseudocode: `fileStream.Write(Encoding.GetBytes(myString))`). You can then flush the `FileStream` or use a buffer size of 1.

Of course it's best if you prevent the process from being terminated in the first place. This usually is straight forward with `Task` as opposed to using raw `Thread`s.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mark it as useful, but mark the @Sidewinder94's answer as accepted because he was the first. I also will consider to use tasks instead of threads, but for now the actual application uses threads so I need a quick solution with threads.